# Are the numbers $\beth_n$ for $n > 0$ signed or unsigned?

Tags: cardinals

By extending the real number line in both directions, I know that $\infty$ or $\aleph_0$ or whatever else you want to call it has a negative, i.e. $-\aleph_0$ is a thing.

Now, of course, $\beth_0 = \aleph_0$, so $-\beth_0$ is also a thing in this sense.
My question is, do $-\beth_1$ and $-\beth_2$ etc. exist as well, or are the Beth Numbers greater than $\beth_0$ all unsigned, as Computer Scientists would say?

Comment: How is $-\aleph_0$ defined?

Comment: The pressing issue is this: Cardinal addition isn't cancellative, so we can't create inverses. That is: What is is $(\aleph_0+1) + (-\aleph_0)$?

Comment: As to extending the real line, I don't want to call the two added points $\aleph_0$ and $-\aleph_0$.

Comment: Ahsim "knows that $\infty$ or $\aleph_0$ ... has a negative."  Well, I don't know that.  Perhaps Ahsim should provide a reference for this amazing thing!

Comment: Ok. So maybe I didn't word my question correctly then. I am nothing more than an amateur at Mathematics, so it's entirely possible I misunderstood something. So, let's ask an intermediate question to further my understanding. When people talk about "$-\infty$", which happens very, very often when talking about infinities (the countable one at least) what do they mean if not "$-\aleph_0$"?